duda sobre eventos wpf
hola amigos tengo una duda sobre el manejo de eventos, tengo 2 botones al hacer click en uno debería hacer clic en el otro, pero que pasa, se pulsa pero no ocurre lo que debería mostrarse en la vista donde se encuentra, es decir no ocurre lo que pasa cuando haces click con el mouse de forma manual, código del primer boton:
<Button  Margin="94 0 23 0"  Name="MiTextBox" Click="Button_Click" >
    <TextBox Text="hola"></TextBox>
</Button>

al pulsar ese botón se desencadena el evento llamado Button_Click, dentro de ese hago una instancia del archivo xaml.cs del otro boton:
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListadoView bcv = new ListadoView();
    bcv.Button_Click2(sender, e);

}

vista del otro boton:
 <Button Grid.Row="2" Width="265" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="14 0 0 0" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource BS}" Command="{Binding BusCommand}" Click="Button_Click2" x:Name="miBoton" >
     <Button.Content>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <mdWpf:PackIcon Width="20" Height="20" Kind="Magnify"/>
             <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 0" Text="Buscar" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </Button.Content>
 </Button >

evento del boton del segundo boton:
public void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("prueba");
}


Un formulario es una clase como cualquier otra clase... es un objeto.. lo unico diferente, es que sabe dibujarse...
Un metodo es un metodo, asi sea un evento o lo que sea.. es un metodo y cualquiera puede llamarlo.
Por lo tanto, no necesitas hacer absolutamente nada de lo que hiciste.
O si, pero esto depende de como este armado tu proyecto..
Si tenes las dos ventanas prendidas al mismo tiempo, las dos ventanas son dos objetos vivos, si queres que se hablen, se tienen que conocer.
Cuando haces
ListadoView bcv = new ListadoView();
bcv.Button_Click2(sender, e);

Estas instanciando un nuevo objeto (no importa si es form o nada, es un nuevo form).. no es el form que ves en pantalla.. es uno nuevo..
Por lo cual, al llamar a ese evento click, estas llamando al evento click dentro de ese formulario...
Si queres comunicar formularios, que cada uno de ellos tenga una referencia al otro.

Entonces como podría acceder al mismo objeto para tener el evento del botón, para no crear uno nuevo?

No conozco como intanciaste los formularios, ni siquiera si estan vivos en el mismo momento.. pero no entendiste mi respuesta no.. es un objeto, como cualquier otro.. si quisieras ver el contenido de un objeto en particular, no instancias otro objeto, si no que tenes un puntero al objeto no... OLVIDATE que es un form.. es un objeto.. y si queres ver lo que tiene ese objeto, necesitas una instancia de ese objeto.. no de uno nuevo...

si están vivos porque el formulario queda de fondo mientras se muestra un dialog por encima.

Perfecto!!! entonces sabes cual es el form... entonces quedate con esa referencia a ese form, y apreta su boton...

si tenes mas dudas, te espero en el [chat]
